# What's the best way to store data with no relation?

Tags: database, mobile, nosql

I'm creating a mobile note application (Android & iOS), and I want to have a server for users to sync notes across multiple devices. At the moment, I store all the notes locally in one single table (SQLite) on each device.
So my question is: What is the best way to store all the notes in my server? 
I'm thinking of creating one table for each user because it would be a waste to scan all other notes when they are completely irrelevant. But I'm not sure if this solution will scale well. 
As regarding DB storage, should I go for traditional db like mysql or no-sql approach? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By relational databases we never add one database / user. You have to add an users table and a notes table, and the notes should have an user id, so they can be filtered out per user. That's all by relational database.

Depending on how many users and notes you have, you can do it with filesystem (an XML or JSON file per user), with SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, or with newSQL databases like voltDB  (ordered by increasing load). It depends on how many notes we are talking about, for example up to 100.000 the PostgreSQL is okay.

By noSQL there are many different database types, each for a specific job. You can find [every noSQL database](http://nosql-database.org/) here. I am not an expert of how to choose noSQL database, but I think in your case a document store like MongoDB or CouchDB is a good choice if you want to store the users and the notes under the same database. But that's just an opinion, I am not an expert of the noSQL topic. You can read more here about [how to model your data in noSQL](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) databases.